# Xamarin: Visual Studio Start iOS app always terminates (found work-around)

Tags: xamarin, ios-simulator, xamarin.forms

- Xamarin Noob
- Xamarin.Forms Noob

  I am all hooked up. Business license on iOS and Android and developing from VS 2013.
  I created the initial sample from [the Xamarin Intro to Forms](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/).

  I 'Start'ed the app and it ran fine on my Mac. I saw the 'Hello, Forms !' label in the running app in the iOS simulator on my Mac Build Machine.

I then replaced the following code in my App.cs

```cs
public static Page GetMainPage()
{
    return new ContentPage
    {
        Content = new Label
        {
            Text = "Hello, Forms !",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        },
    };
}
```

with:

```cs
public static Page GetMainPage()
{
    return new ContentPage()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 10,
            Children =
            {
                new Label
                {
                    Text = "Stop",
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(20)
                },
                new Label
                {
                    Text = "Slow down",
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
                    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(20)
                },
                new Label
                {
                    Text = "Go",
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
                    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(20)
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

That's all I did, but now the app will not run in the simulator - it always exists as soon as it starts...

I put the original code back again, and it still doesn't start.

I always see (in My VS 12013 Mac Server Log)

```
[10-Nov-2014 15:43:32] Request handled in 4.129ms
[10-Nov-2014 15:43:37] Request handled in 3.728ms
[10-Nov-2014 15:43:40] stdout: Starting iPhone 5s
Launching application
Application launched. PID = 2872
Press enter to terminate the application
>
Application Terminated
[10-Nov-2014 15:43:42] Request handled in 3.898ms
[10-Nov-2014 15:43:48] Request handled in 4.031ms
etc....
```

I have exited both the iOS simulator and VS 2013, paired them again, all to no avail...

What could possibly be wrong?

**EDIT**
Infact, when the app becomes visible in the simulators view of icons, clicking it brings up the original version of "Hello, Forms!" - so my new code is never deployed to the simulator...

**EDIT 2**
 Ok, I got the new content moving and got it running:

I had to manually "Reset content on device" in the iOS simulator on the Mac.
 I also had to manually clean each project in VS 2013 - just rebuilding the solution doesn't do anything to the content being sent to the Mac iOS simulator server, I guess.

I hope this helps someone as new as I am.

Comment: think this might be an issue with the current stable version and vis studio 2013 professional. I currently have the same issue. the only work around is to delete the bin and deploy. DONT build the solution, just click deploy. its an issue with the copying of the Info.plist file onto the mac mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing "." from your app's name in Info.plist file.

Comment: I'll try this, but this is the 'default' naming convention from Xamarin when you create a new project...you think they woulda tested that? :)

Comment: Helped me, not sure if it will help you but worth trying :)

Comment: This helped with a number of items - the app loading image also displays correctly now. I renamed my portable project and deleted all obj and bin directories to help the solution be 'cleaned' from old named dll's.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling..

The way to fix this is to change the build config on the solution.

In a fresh Xamarin.Forms solution in Visual Studio, you might have:

```
Solution 'MyXFormsSample' (3 projects)
 v MyXFormsSample (Portable)
   > Properties
   > References
   > App.cs
     packages.config
 > MyXFormsSample.Android
 > MyXFormsSample.iOS
```

It seems that by default, in the **solution's Configuration Manager's** build configuration, the portable code project is *not set to build* for the iPhoneSimulator platform

I clicked that on for the debug, and also release, solution configurations, and still I had to Reset Content on the Mac's iOS simulator before debugging, then all I had to do was press the green 'Start' button in the menu - all was updated and released to the Mac Build server's iOS Simulator.